# PocketSphinx Native Crash

Tags: android, segmentation-fault, cmusphinx

On some devices (none of the actual test devices), I get a force close when I start PocketSphinx recognition. I am trying to get a log file from one of the devices, but it is difficult because none of the devices I've tested with have this error. Let me know if it would be helpful to attach a log from my device...

```
Build fingerprint: 'motorola/falcon_retla_ds/falcon_umtsds:4.4.2/KXB20.25-1.31/15:user/release-keys'
Revision: 'p3c0'
pid: 31820, tid: 31820, name: OpenMic.Pheonix >>> com.RSen.OpenMic.Pheonix <<<
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00000004
r0 5f6b80b0 r1 63075650 r2 00000000 r3 61547071
r4 00000000 r5 63075668 r6 63075650 r7 29200025
r8 61700021 r9 5f6b80b0 sl 4013e384 fp be853494
ip 00000001 sp be8533f0 lr 6151134b pc 61511752 cpsr 600b0030
d0 616e6f6974636964 d1 73692027656c6775
d2 676e697373696d20 d3 20656874206e6920
d4 3fc39a09d078c69f d5 bfb9e1d043becc6e
d6 fffa610ebb911ee4 d7 c1167bcba4c7c034
d8 441700000000025c d9 0000000043d0b500
d10 0000000000000000 d11 0000000000000000
d12 0000000000000000 d13 0000000000000000
d14 0000000000000000 d15 0000000000000000
d16 3ff0000000000000 d17 3fe62e42fee00000
d18 4000000000000000 d19 3fd999a089aebe17
d20 3f66599a4f355e73 d21 3fe55559cb1b06d5
d22 3fd2492a41711b21 d23 3fcc71cead6ed79f
d24 3fc7466dd43ef558 d25 3fc2f112df3e5244
d26 c0426bb1bb911ee4 d27 3fb37323632971e0
d28 3dea39ef35793c76 d29 3f8f66d8678dd29f
d30 3fb8107bdde3fe78 d31 3faf0c90ac6f6f18
scr 20000013

backtrace:
#00 pc 0000e752 /data/app-lib/com.RSen.OpenMic.Pheonix-2/libpocketsphinx_jni.so
#01 pc 0000e347 /data/app-lib/com.RSen.OpenMic.Pheonix-2/libpocketsphinx_jni.so (Java_edu_cmu_pocketsphinx_PocketSphinxJNI_Decoder_1setKws+94)
#02 pc 0002034c /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmPlatformInvoke+112)
#03 pc 00050e6b /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallJNIMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)+398)
#04 pc 00052859 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmResolveNativeMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)+184)
#05 pc 000297e0 /system/lib/libdvm.so
#06 pc 00030ae8 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmMterpStd(Thread*)+76)
#07 pc 0002e180 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+184)
#08 pc 00063751 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInvokeMethod(Object*, Method const*, ArrayObject*, ArrayObject*, ClassObject*, bool)+392)
#09 pc 0006b713 /system/lib/libdvm.so
#10 pc 000297e0 /system/lib/libdvm.so
#11 pc 00030ae8 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmMterpStd(Thread*)+76)
#12 pc 0002e180 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+184)
#13 pc 0006346d /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethodV(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, bool, JValue*, std::__va_list)+336)
#14 pc 0004ca37 /system/lib/libdvm.so
#15 pc 0004d0f7 /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
#16 pc 0004de1b /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::start(char const*, char const*)+354)
#17 pc 0000105b /system/bin/app_process
#18 pc 0000e41b /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_init+50)
#19 pc 00000d7c /system/bin/app_process

code around pc:
61511730 fa8ef004 33016ea3 68a266a3 2b006f13 
61511740 4628dce0 0000bd38 4614b538 6a024b0b 
61511750 6062447b 220df240 46086985 f02b4619 
61511760 4622fc09 46284601 fb84f02d d00242a0 
61511770 695b6803 20004798 bf00bd38 0003591d 
61511780 4604b538 b1b86980 fcb0f02d 686be00b 
61511790 f02b6818 686bfc22 68036898 4798695b 
615117a0 f02d4628 4605fc81 d1f02800 f02d69a0 
615117b0 69a0fb31 fcacf02d 61a32300 bd3861e3 
615117c0 460cb570 4605490f 461a4610 23004479 
615117d0 fcfaf02f 46064621 f02c6828 b960f893 
615117e0 46304909 f7fd4479 b130edda eddcf7fd 
615117f0 46216828 f02c4632 4630f8a1 4070e8bd 
61511800 bbebf02b 000358d4 000358be 00004770 
61511810 44784801 bf004770 0004391a 33016843 
61511820 47706043 4604b510 6840b1f0 60603801 

code around lr:
61511328 6823b14f 46394620 f8d32200 479832a4 
61511338 b9084605 463de022 4648462a f0004631 
61511348 2800fb0c da094602 a8034912 f7fd4479 
61511358 4620eff8 f7ffa903 e00ff9f3 6823b136 
61511368 46414620 f8d34632 479832a8 6823b135 
61511378 46394620 f8d3462a 479832a8 f8da9a13 
61511388 429a3000 f7fdd001 b014efe2 87f0e8bd 
61511398 00044b7c 00035c71 b085b5f0 46044616 
615113a8 e9cd9d0b 22002300 e9cd2300 b1452302 
615113b8 46296803 f8d32200 479832a4 b9084607 
615113c8 462fe012 46304639 fa6cf000 fde2f01f 
615113d8 b1379002 46206823 463a4629 32a8f8d3 
615113e8 e9dd4798 e0010102 21002000 bdf0b005 
615113f8 41f0e92d 4f1cb094 e9cd4604 447f2300 
61511408 9e1b683f 8000f8dd 9313683b 6803b146 
61511418 22004631 32a4f8d3 46054798 e01ab908
```

Comment: Also it seems that the majority of devices that get this error are Moto G's, is that relevant?

Comment: You need to attach with gdb and collect a backtrace with a debugger if you can reproduce this problem. Otherwise it seems like you need to get Motorola somewhere.

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev Ok thank you, I'll post this when I get it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was caused by a different issue than I suspected... I allow users to determine what phrase to look for and while I was validating new phrases I forgot to validate old ones. This led to some phrases including words not included in the dictionary causing for PocketSphinx to crash